# AWS instance running tomcat with different web services cannot be accessed using IP and port

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, war, virtualhost, tomcat8

I'm working with several web services in the same instance and wanted to know how to solve some issues: I'm using an AWS instance that is running Tomcat 8. Tomcat is managing 3 different .war web services, each one of them running on a different port and pointing to a different url (app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com and app3.mydomain.com). Right now all of the web services are running with no problems and I can perform some REST actions (like POST or GET) over them, but only if the REST instruction is sent via the url (app1.mydomain.com/serviceapp1 or app2.mydomain.com/serviceapp2). On the other hand, if I try to access the services using the IP address and port (xx.xx.xx.xx:Port1/serviceapp1 or xx.xx.xx.xx:Port2/serviceapp2) I get error messages like "page can't be found". As it is an AWS instance, the /etc/hosts file contains each one of the urls shown above pointing to the url of the machine within the amazon local network (192.168.x.xx, got with ifconfig), not to the public IP (38.xx.xx.xx).

Can you please let me know what can I do with these settings to access the webapps through IP address and not via the url?

What can I do to set the Aliases in the server.xml file correctly since I'm using subdomains (app1.mydomain.com) and not a typical www.mydomain.com url?

Since the server.xml file contains a service for each one of the webapps and has it own port, which par of the setting should I review to reach these web services via the IP address and port instead of the url?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you want to access via the private IP or via the public or elastic IP? Are you accessing this from another resource in your AWS VPC, or from outside your VPC?

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your answer. Int his case I'm trying to access through the public IP, from a resource outside the VPC

Comment: Why do you want to access this via IP instead of domain name? IPs can change unless you've assigned Elastic IPs to every instance. Domain names are the preferred method.

Comment: HI Mark,Thanks for your answer. I agree with you, the domain name is the most generic solution, however since I'm getting recently involved on this topic, I wanted to know why this is happening. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. To associate an IP address to your URLs, please use Route53. You may create an A record and associate it to your IP address directly, or use aliases.
2. To associate subdomains, one way is to Route53 aliases. The other way is to use a forward proxy like CloudFront; Associate your cloudfront domain to your subdomain URL and then create a CNAME in your domain which point the cloudfront CDN to your URL.
3. You may also read about ELB path-based routing. In some cases, this may be a good fit to your design.

Comment: Hi Sam,

Thanks for your answer. Since Route53 is an additional tool, first I wanted to know how to solve it without additional tools, since the implemented virtualhost is not too complex. Anyway I will try your solution and let you know the results

Comment: The question is about using IP address **instead of** domain names. Route53 is just for setting up domain names. There is no reason you would need Route53 for this. This answer does not address the question being asked at all.